# Shell script to connect 4 different servers and run a command taken input from a file

Tags: shell, scripting

I need to create a script which will connect 4 different servers one by one, and check if the server is running then execute a command and exit. If first server is not running then connect to second and exit.

I am thinking about connecting through SSH script using key based authentication.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
hosts="host1 host2 host3"

for h in $hosts; do
    ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=7 $h command
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && break
done
```

Comment: Hi Sputnick :- Thanks a lot for the reply...this is working perfectly fine but its running on all the server, but what I need is it should connect to first server if its up run the command and exit the script no need to run further. if first server is not running then connect to second run the command and exit and process will go on till 4th server

Comment: You should "accept" the question if it was well answered, that's how this site works ;=

Comment: Hi Sputnick.....Sorry for the late reply I wasn't able to update it but yes it worked for me...thanks a lot